# Name of the helping lines from Notepadd++

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, sublimetext2, notepad++

Iam searching the name of the lines, witch are helping by reading code.
I found it the first time on Notepad++, sublime-text2 and in IntelliJ.
I don't know what the name is to search it for my eclipse.

Comment: You should really include a visual. We're having to magically _guess_ what lines you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

- folding
- indentation guides

  There's an eclipse plugin for that, it seems: https://github.com/atlanto/IndentGuide